# I keep getting this error when I use create method in sequelize. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js

I keep getting this error when I use create method in sequelize:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Here is my code:

Signup.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const {models: { Employees } } = require('../models')
// const  Employees  = require('../models/Employees')(sequelize, DataTypes); 
// const  Employees  = require('../models/Employees').Employees; 

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const employees = await Employees.findAll()
    res.json(employees)
})
router.post('/', async(req, res)=>{
    const employee = req.body
    await Employees.create(employee)
    res.json(employee)
})

module.exports = router
```

and heres my employees model

```
const {sequelize, DataTypes} = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Employees = sequelize.define("Employees", {
       
        firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
        middlename: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        phoneNo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        department: DataTypes.STRING,        
    })

    return Employees
}
```

and my index.js for the models

```
const dbConfig = require('../config/db.config')

const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DATABASE, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
    host: dbConfig.HOST,
    dialect: dbConfig.DIALECT
})

const db = {};
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.models = {};
db.models.Emmployees = require('./Employees')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
db.models.Assets = require('./Assets')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);

module.exports = db
```

I tried the paths which are commented on the signup.js which are:

```
const  Employees  = require('../models/Employees')(sequelize, DataTypes); 
const  Employees  = require('../models/Employees').Employees;
```

both didn't work but I used the same kind of import for another model like the one that I actually used in the signup.js and it worked fine.

Comment: You make a typo, compare: `Employees` in `Signup.js` and `db.models.Emmployees` in `index.js`

Comment: Thank you brother, It was painful tho